# The arithmetic of higher genus curves

Tags: reference-request, higher-genus-curves, nt.number-theory

Genus 0 curves are well understood in number theory. There is also are rich theory a bunch of conjectures about the arithmetic of elliptic curves.

This leads me to the question, what we know about higher genus curves.
The only thing that comes to my mind is Falting's theorem saying that 
any such curve has only finitely many points.

Coming from the theory of elliptic curves one might ask a lot of questions:

1. Under BSD there is an algorithm computing a basis for Mordell-Weil group
   of the elliptic curve.
   Is it expected that such an algorithm will also exist for higher genus curves that 
   determines all the rational points, or even proven to exists assuming some big
   conjectures such as ABC or Vojta's conjectures. Or does Matiyasevich theorem
   imply that such an algorithm is not possible?
2. Do special values of $L$-functions of these curves tell us anything interesting about
   these curves. I know that there is a generalization of BSD to abelian varieties
   and hence to Jacobians of higher genus curves, but does the $L$-functions also 
   tells something about the curve itself.
3. The local-global principle does not hold for elliptic curves. However, (conjecturally
   through BSD) local information does indeed give information about global properties. 
   So I regard BSD as a fancier or refined version of local-global principle, since the 
   pure local-global principle does not hold. Is there also a fanicer local-global 
   principle for higher genus curves.

I am not particulary asking answers for these questions, since these are only examples and I could post more. I am rather asking for a place to look, where things like these are treated.

Thanks

Comment: [It's Faltings' theorem, not Falting's]

Comment: In fact, according to Milne's style page, it should be Faltings's theorem.  I don't know whether this is generally accepted style or not, however.

Comment: @wood : in your point 3, do you mean that the local-global principle does not hold for *genus one* curves ?

Comment: definitely Faltings's; Faltings' means it was proved by multiple people named Falting.

Comment: The very first line of Strunk and White's *The Elements of Style* is "Form the possessive singular of nouns by adding 's ". The second is: "Follow this rule whatever the final consonant. Charles's friend..."
 

Comment: "Under BSD there is an algorithm computing a basis for Mordell-Weil group of the elliptic curve."
$$ $$
Are you assuming you can compute the rank numerically, in particular can tell analytic rank 2 with $L''$ small from rank 4? I don't want to change your subject via an apostrophic comment, but I'm not completely convinced there is an algorithm for computing the rank even if one assumes (full) BSD. After a bit of thought, I think it is right (rank 2 with $L''$ can be eliminated via regulator bounds), but I'd like to have a reference for my own use. :-P

Comment: I think Faltings' is more common, though either are correct.  I usually write "Langlands's ..." but I think I'm the only one.

Comment: @Junkie : See William Stein's online book http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/bsd/bsd.pdf (Prop. 1.5). That the running time of this algorithm is finite uses BSD.

Comment: I'd say Stein's proof of Proposition 1.3 could be more clear. Just since we can compute $L^{(k)}(E,1)$ to any desired precision, this is meaningless because we have no lower bound (at least not perspicaciously) for any nonzero L-derivative. I agree that this can be turned into a proof if we exert care: Stein doesn't explicitly say so, but we increase the precision so small $L′′$ will eventually be noticed as nonzero. Or we could apply full BSD so the Reg can be related to heights of known points. With full BSD, I think one can make the running time effective, which is what I really wanted.

Comment: @all With "under BSD" I indeed meant full BSD

Comment: My understanding is that under the BSD rank formula, there is an algorithm to compute E(Q) which terminates (but the running time is far from effective). I'm not sure we can make the running time effective, even with full BSD : how do you get an upper bound for the height up to which one should perform the search of rational points ? (do you assume one is also given in advance the rank, the regulator or the leading term of the L-function ?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a conjecture (or variants of one) due to Scharaschkin, Skorobogatov and Stoll predicting that Brauer-Manin or finite descent obstructions (these are fancy forms of a local-global principle) determine all rational points. This gives an algorithm to determine if the set of points is empty or not. See Stoll, Algebra and Number Theory 2 (2008), 595–611. The algorithm is actually practical, as demonstrated by Bruin and Stoll (for genus two over the rationals). This answers your 3 and part of 1.

For the rest of 1, Vojta's conjecture or ABC (with some choice of constant which in the original conjectures is not specified) would give an upper bound for the height of rational points on a curve and would allow the determination of all such points by a finite search.

The answer for 2 is (likely) "no".

Answer (score 7):

You might take a look at

Cassels, J. W. S.; Flynn, E. V. *Prolegomena to a middlebrow arithmetic of curves of genus* 2. London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 230. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1996. xiv+219 pp. ISBN: 0-521-48370-0

They develop much of the descent theory and theory of homogeneous spaces explicitly for curves of genus 2.

Concerning question (2), as Felipe suggests, the L-series of the curve contains the same information as the L-series of its Jacobian, so BSwD will tell you about the rank of the Jacobian and the height of generators for $J(K)$. In particular, if $L(1)\ne 0$, then the rank is 0, so $C(K)$ consists of torsion points, which would allow one to effectively determine $C(K)$. In general, it is reasonable to suppose that there might be a bound for the height of the largest point in $C(K)$ in terms of a generating set for $J(K)$ (although such a bound is not currently known). Then BSwD would give a bound for the latter, and hence for the former.